# Finding out which Linux process was executing when system locked up by evaluating CPU registers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-management

I need to find out what is executing when my Linux (Debian) system hangs (x86 platform). I managed to extract the following information just before the system locked up:

```
es: 0x7B
cs: 0x73
ss: 0x7B
ds: 0x7B
fs: 0x0
gs: 0x33
ldtbase: 0x0
tr: 0x80
dr7: 0x400
dr6: 0xFFFF0FF0
eax: 0xBFBDE820
ecx: 0xA908F9A0
edx: 0xB708A000
ebx: 0xB71B5278
esp: 0xBFBDE730
ebp: 0xBFBDE838
esi: 0x9D36B58
edi: 0x9D50BB8
eip: 0xB71B13E8
eflags: 0x203206
cr3: 0x1E9DE000
cr0: 0x80050033
```

From the values of the segment registers, I know that when Linux hangs, it's on user-space mode. What I would like to find out is which process/library is causing the crash, and ideally which exact part of it.

By looking at CR3 and EIP, I should be able to get this information but I am getting confused. As far as I know, the virtual address 0xB71B13E8 is relative to the page table used (0x1E9DE000).
Now, the instruction pointer points to a physical address, right? I think I should convert this (EIP value) to a virtual address which would be the offset of the page table pointed by CR3.

Could anyone please help me a bit on that?

Comment: How did you obtain this information?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you extract the information from?

If this is a usermode crash/lockup, presumably this information is from a core dump (you can dump cores on the fly without necessarily killing the subject)

In that case, use `gdb /usr/bin/myprogrambinary corefile`

And navigate using gdb commands `bt`, `info threads`, `info shared`, `thread apply all bt full` etc

The usefulness of all this will greatly improve with debugging symbols for the various libraries installed on your system (depending on your distro, install the relevant *-dbg packages)